# Laravel - Setting null to model columns has no effect

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set a null value on a Model column but it gets ignored and it doesn't update.

```
if($rol_colegio)
    $update_pl['rol_colegio'] = $rol_colegio; //$rol_colegio may be null

$usuario->update($update_pl);
```

The data *does get* updated successfully when I try to use non-null data, but if the variable is null this entry doesn't get updated.

What would be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$rol_colegion = null` doesn't match condition `if($rol_colegio)`.

Just remove `if($rol_colegio)`.

Comment: I'm banging my head on the desk at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do like this.

```
$update_pl['rol_colegio'] = $rol_colegio; //$rol_colegio may be null

$usuario->update($update_pl);
```